# Want to find only files from X last days

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to search directory and find the files from last x days, currently my function return all the time same file (who created 2 days ago) even if I search more than 2 days.

```
decimal days = nudDays.Value; 
//read the number from NumericUpDown comtrol

private void setDays() 
//each change in NumericUpDown comtrol will change days variable
{
    if (nudDays.Value != 0)
    {
        days = nudDays.Value;    
    }
    else
    {
        days = decimal.MaxValue;
    }            
}
```

Checks whether my file created in the last x days (days variable):

```
public bool checkFileCreationDate(FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    double num = (double)nudDays.Value * -1;
    if (fileInfo.CreationTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(num))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would do it the other way around: `if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(fileInfo.CreationTime) < days) { ... }` That way, you won’t have possible strange problems when `decimal.MaxValue` is used.

Comment: Are you sure there are files that should be returning `true` but are not? Have you stepped through?

Comment: Debug it with breakpoint in checkFileCreationDate method!

Comment: well, the code you've posted has almost none of the crucial logic in it.  As much as I don't like the storing of your days as a `decimal` type, and then converting that to `double` among other things, I can't see any specific flaws in the logic you've posted

Comment: also, in the mean time, [Try Using the Debugger.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging), and make sure that everything that you think is happening actually is happening

Comment: if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(fileInfo.CreationTime).Days < days) still give me my file who created 2 days ago in any value of days

Comment: what code you think is missing in my example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this statement:

> currently my function return all the time same file (who created 2 days ago) even if I search more than 2 days.

I believe what you want to do is change this line:

```
if (fileInfo.CreationTime > DateTime.Now.AddDays(num))
```

To this:

```
if (fileInfo.CreationTime == DateTime.Now.AddDays(num))
```

However, I have to admit, it's not that clear *exactly* what you're looking for so I hope I interpreted it right.

### UPDATE

If you want all files that were created within the past `n` number of days (i.e. if `n` were 6 then it would return any files 1-6 days old), then use this:

```
public bool checkFileCreationDate(FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    double num = (double)nudDays.Value;
    if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(fileInfo.CreationTime).TotalDays <= num)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If you want all files that are `n` days old (i.e. if `n` were 6 then it would return any files exactly 6 days old), then use this:

```
public bool checkFileCreationDate(FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    double num = (double)nudDays.Value;
    if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(fileInfo.CreationTime).TotalDays == num)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you **want**, we'll work backwards from there.

Comment: i want to received only the file who created in the last x days

Comment: @user1269592: So, if you provided a number (6) in the control, you would expect any file created in the last 6 days? In other words, if the file was created 1 day ago it would also be included - but if a file was created exactly 6 days ago it would also be included?

Comment: Yes it's true even though it does not have to be exact just at the same same time

Comment: the new code (first method) didn't returned any files from today even if my x days is 1 or 2 or bigger

Comment: @user1269592, it appears that's because your original code example was taking the value `* -1`, and I left that in from the copy, try it again.

Comment: now it's working thanks ! BTW, if i want to get all my file without considering created time by set the value to 0, can i just set days = decimal.MaxValue; ?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using linq pass in the Date value that you are looking for

```
Date somedate;
var filterFiles = from file in directoryInfo.GetFiles() 
            where file.CreationTime > somedate
            select file;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your time horizon is longer than  two days, the file created two days ago will be included. That is ok, because "four days" actually translates into the interval [now-4d .. now]

To exclude your test file, you have to reduce the day number to one.

Be aware that fileInfo.CreationTime and fileInfo.LastWriteTime are different in many cases.
You might want to filter for LastWriteTime.